# Can I run MarkLogic optic 'where' with cts.Query in "filtered" manner

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-10, marklogic-optic-api

In my Marklogic Optic queries I am using:

1. [AccessPlan.prototype.where](https://docs.marklogic.com/10.0/AccessPlan.prototype.where)
2. [op.fromSearch](https://docs.marklogic.com/10.0/op.fromSearch)

with [cts.fieldWordQuery](https://docs.marklogic.com/10.0/cts.fieldWordQuery) as a cts.Query but this query always run as "unfiltered" and gives me false-positives.
Can I somehow pass some options there or "trick" Optic to act as "filtered" query?
I didn't find anything in documentation beside the note from ML11 documentation [op.FromSearch in ML11](https://docs.marklogic.com/11.0/op.fromSearch)
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Per the docs at https://docs.marklogic.com/op.fromSearch , you unfortunately cannot perform a filtered query given that Optic queries are resolved against the row index.